# How to compile and test functions in ocaml?

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml

For my summer programming course I need to compile and test several functions from an ocaml file (a .ml file) our teacher gave us. I've never programmed in ocaml before, but I downloaded it on my ubuntu vm and not I can't figure out how to compile it and test the functions from the terminal.

I'm also curious if I need to add print statements to the code in order to test them, since ocaml doesn't require main methods. If so, how do I print the return value of a function?

Thank you for your help, I apologize if this is a newbie question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors did you get specifically? ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). If you're not facing any specific errors, here's a great quickstart guide on setting up an OCaml project: https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/quickstart_ocaml_project_dune.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have installed OCaml properly, by running the OCaml interactive toplevel (don't type `$` this is a prompt from your shell):

   ```
   $ ocaml
   ```

   It should show something like this:

   ```
   OCaml version 4.07.0
   #
   ```

   The `#` symbol is a prompt, you can type OCaml definitions there and send them to the interpreter using the `;;` terminating sequence (again don't type `#` it is also a prompt symbol), e.g.,

   ```
   # print_endline "Hello, world";;
   Hello, world
   - : unit = ()
   #
   ```

   Hint: to enable history install `rlwrap` with `sudo apt install rlwrap` and run the `ocaml` toplevel as

   ```
   $ rlwrap ocaml
   ```
2. Now, we are ready to compile our first program. In OCaml, like in Python, all top-level definitions in your program are evaluated in order of their appearance, therefore you don't need to have a special `main` function. Despite this fact, I'm usually defining one, using the following idiom

   ```
   let main () = 
     print_endline "Hello, world"

   (* the entry point - just call the main function *)
   let () = main ()
   ```

   Now, create a new folder (make sure it is empty)

   ```
   $ mkdir my-first-ocaml-program
   $ cd my-first-ocaml-program
   ```

   and put the OCaml code above into a file named `test.ml` (the filename doesn't  have any special meaning for the compiler toolchain, but I will reference this name in the shell commands below).

   let's test that everything is correct, by printing the contents of the `test.ml` file

   ```
   $ cat test.ml
   ```

   and the output should be

   ```
   let main () =
     print_endline "Hello, world"


   (* the entry point - just call the main function *)
   let () = main ()
   ```

   Now, let's compile and run at the same time,

   ```
   $ ocamlbuild test.native --
   ```

   And we should see the `"Hello, world"`,

   ```
   Finished, 4 targets (4 cached) in 00:00:00.
   Hello, world
   ```

   The first line is the output from the compiler (ignore it, unless it is different). Starting from the second line it is our output. Here are some explanations on the build one-liner, `ocamlbuild test.native`. It uses `ocamlbuild`, an easy to use but powerful OCaml build tool. The `test.native` tells `ocamlbuild` that you want to build a native (machine code) binary and that `test.ml` is the main source file. You can also ask to build a bytecode binary, e.g., `test.byte`. This is called a *target* in ocamlbuild parlance. The `--` is optional, and it tells ocamlbuild to run the built target as soon as it is ready. Any argument past `--` is passed to your program as command line arguments.
3. What about larger programs or programs with dependencies?  The good news is that you can put your code in several files in the *same* folder, and ocamlbuild will be clever enough to build them in the proper order (it will do the dependency analysis, compiling, and linking for you - all seamlessly). If you need to use some external package, then you can specify it via the `-pkg` option. For example, let's assume that we're using the `fileutils` package to implement our version of the `ls` program<sup>1</sup>. Let's update our `test.ml` so that it now is having the following contents:

   ```
   $ cat test.ml
   let main () =
     FileUtil.ls "." |> List.iter print_endline


   (* the entry point - just call the main function *)
   let () = main ()
   ```

   and, as usual, build and print in one

   ```
    $ ocamlbuild -pkg fileutils test.native --
    Finished, 4 targets (4 cached) in 00:00:00.
    ./test.native
    ./_build
    ./test.ml
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>) How to install a package is system dependent. E.g., if you're using `apt` to install OCaml then you can do `sudo apt install libfileutils-ocaml-dev`. If you're using opam (the recommended way), then it is just `opam install fileutils`. In any case, package installation is out of the scope of this question, I'm assuming that in your course you would be using some packages pre-installed. We use `fileutils` here just as an example, which you can easily adapt to your own purposes.